# User logged in as different Facebook user

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm using parse.com services and Facebook API.

This week, whenever I want to login to my app with my Facebook account, it crashes.

I've added a toast message that will show me the error on ParseException. 

The message on the toast is:
"User logged in as different Facebook user".

I tried to search about online, but none of the solutions helped me.

Comment: By the way, I've just tried to switch account and it still shows me the message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same case. And it was because of the auth id of your app in Facebook platform. Maybe your app is not linked with the Facebook app profile. Take a look in the next URL: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

- auth.statusChange:

Typically you will want to use the auth.authResponseChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:

1. Connected
2. Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
3. Not logged into Facebook at all.